# como converter um numero para real (dinheiro)?

Tags: javascript, html5

Segue o código

```
var n1 = 155551.15
document.write(`${n1.toFixed(2).replace('.' ,  ',')}`)
n1.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
```

Mas na hora de ver o número não muda para real ...
Alguma ajuda ?

Comment: Você quer exibir no HTML o valor de n1 em formato real R$?

Comment: exato, mas na pagina o numero fica normal e não muda o simbolo de real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você na verdade escreveu o valor de `n1` no HTML com o método `toFixed`, enquanto deveria ter feito isso com o método `toLocaleString`.

O uso do método `toLocaleString` está correto, porém você utilizou ele e não fez nada com o retorno.

```js
let n1 = 155551.15;

document.write(`${n1.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })}`);
```

O trecho do código com o `toFixed` não é necessário.

Comment: Obrigado, então o uso do .tofixed  e .replace ja é feito no metodo toLocaleString correto ?

Comment: Ele já faz a formatação completa: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Muito obrigado !!!